# Serializing an object to JSON

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, nsarray

I am new to the JSON format, but it looks ideal for what I am attempting. I need to take a custom `NSObject` (a recipe) and send it via a URL string in an email. The recipient will then open the link in my app and the URL will be parsed.

My existing implementation manually builds a string from the recipe’s details and decodes it on the other end. I would prefer to use something more standard, like JSON.

So far I have added the following method to my `Recipe` class:

```
- (NSData *)jsonRepresentation
{
    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"name":self.name,
                         @"instructions":self.instructions};
    NSError* error;
    return [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary
                                           options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                             error:&error];
}
```

I can successfully log this `NSData` object using:

```
 [[NSString alloc]initWithData:recipe.jsonRepresentation
                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

However, I can’t yet add my list of ingredients (an `NSArray`). I attempted to simply use this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ @"name" : self.name,
                      @"instructions" : self.instructions,
                       @"ingredients" : self.orderedIngredients };
```

but on logging, I receive this error:

```
Invalid type in JSON write (Ingredient)
```

As you can tell, I’m pretty new at this.

Am I meant to do something to the `ingredients` array before I add it to the dictionary?

Comment: Note: I am not using any third party frameworks and would prefer not to for now, until I know what I am doing.

Comment: What is ingredient object? You should write a method in that class to return an NSDictionary or so before adding to the current dictionary.

Comment: An ingredient is a custom object with a few properties. The only one I care about here is the name.

Comment: If name is all that you want, check with my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ @"name" : self.name,
                      @"instructions" : self.instructions,
                       @"ingredients" : [self.orderedIngredients valueForKey:@"name"] };
```

Assuming that `self.orderedIngredients` is an array with `ingredients` objects in it and that `ingredients` has a property called `name` in it,

```
[self.orderedIngredients valueForKey:@"name"]
```

will return an array of all names.

Comment: Thank you. Very succinct. I only wish XCode could make it look as pretty.

Answer (score 1):

If your list of ingredients array holds custom class objects, you should create a serializer for that class.

Comment: Ok - I'm not clear how I would do that, but I see the distinction. Could I instead use an array of the ingredients' names?

Comment: @user1111278, +1. I agree with the `serializer` part if we have to convert all the properties of `ingredients` into a JSON.